# ISerializable-derived class, via FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers() in c#

Tags: c#

A derived class that implements ISerializable, whose based class does NOT, can de/serialise both members of based class and itself. In the derived class, FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers() is used to get the based class's members, **it should return both field and property based on MSDN. However, in the code below, it only return field.** Any idea?

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wttcc22.aspx)

```
internal static class ISerializableVersioning {
   public static void Go() {
      using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
         BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
         formatter.Serialize(stream, new Derived());
         stream.Position = 0;
         Derived d = (Derived)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
         Console.WriteLine(d);
      }
   }

   [Serializable]
   private class Base {
      protected String m_name = "base";
      protected String Name { get { return m_name; } set { m_name = value; } }
      public Base() { /* Make the type instantiable*/ }
   }

   [Serializable]
   private class Derived : Base, ISerializable {
      new private String m_name = "derived";
      public Derived() { /* Make the type instantiable*/ }

      // If this constructor didn't exist, we'd get a SerializationException
      // This constructor should be protected if this class were not sealed
      [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, SerializationFormatter = true)]
      private Derived(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
         // Get the set of serializable members for our class and base classes
         Type baseType = this.GetType().BaseType;
         MemberInfo[] mi = FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(baseType, context);

         // Deserialize the base class's fields from the info object
         for (Int32 i = 0; i < mi.Length; i++) {
            // Get the field and set it to the deserialized value
            FieldInfo fi = (FieldInfo)mi[i];
            fi.SetValue(this, info.GetValue(baseType.FullName + "+" + fi.Name, fi.FieldType));
         }

         // Deserialize the values that were serialized for this class
         m_name = info.GetString("Name");
      }

      [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, SerializationFormatter = true)]
      public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
         // Serialize the desired values for this class
         info.AddValue("Name", m_name);

         // Get the set of serializable members for our class and base classes
         Type baseType = this.GetType().BaseType;

//**Should GetSerializableMembers return both the field and property? But it only return field here**
         MemberInfo[] mi = FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(baseType, context);

         // Serialize the base class's fields to the info object
         for (Int32 i = 0; i < mi.Length; i++) {
            // Prefix the field name with the fullname of the base type
             object value = ((FieldInfo) mi[i]).GetValue(this);
            info.AddValue(baseType.FullName + "+" + mi[i].Name, value);
         }
      }
      public override String ToString() {
         return String.Format("Base Name={0}, Derived Name={1}", base.Name, m_name);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GetSerializableMembers returns a MemberInfo array; you are casting them all to FieldInfo even though they could be EventInfo, MethodBase, or PropertyInfo objects.

Comment: it returns only one element of FieldInfo type.